# Clear command returns 'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type

Tags: command-line

Just now, the clear command has not been working and returning `'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type. %!s(<nil>)` However, I have already scoured the web looking for an answer, and have not found one, I have tried setting my terminal to `linux`, `ansi`, and a few others with no luck. I am running x64 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you close and open a new terminal are you still seeing that?

Comment: Yes, it's always the same. The exact same situation I described.

Comment: I've seen something similar especially when I was running ssh through my Mac with my urxvt terminal.  All I had to do was to set a TERM type to solve the issue.  I am not sure what `%!s(<nil>)` is though.  Possible:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213726/ssh-from-screen-leads-to-unknown-terminal-error

Comment: Thanks Terrance, I’ve already seen that post though, and tried the fixes, tomorrow im going to try tobtest more with other terminals and uninstalling and reinstalling. None of those fixes have worked, and I am also trying to figure out what '''%!s(<nil>)''' means. We’ll see.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the `%!s(<nil>)`. I wonder if the terminfo database file is missing or corrupted? It might be worth running `clear` under strace and looking for terminfo related messages ex. `strace clear 2>&1 | grep -A3 terminfo`

Comment: Thanks for the answer steeldriver, unfortunately the command returned nothing. I don't know what that means, however I did find that it looks like TTY1 and TTY2 both have desktop environments running I don't know if that means anything but I thought I should share. EDIT: Clearing things up TTY1 has a login screen that just takes me back to TTY2 I think it always does this. I'm not sure if this is the way ubuntu works or if this is a problem. I don't believe it used to do this. I also deleted a file a bit ago, to make my NVIDIA drivers work because they were crashing my laptop. It was in X11.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I found the error. I needed to add `alias clear="TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo TERM=xterm /usr/bin/clear"` to my .bashrc file.